# Install System C to Cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin, systemc

I am trying to install System C 2.3.0 to Cygwin (1.7.25). I am running the ../configure in the objdir (as many tutorials online state) but i get the following error:

checking for gcc... gcc 
checking for C compiler default output file name...
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

/*Snippet of config.log */




gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)

configure:2851: $? = 0

configure:2858: gcc -V >&5

gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'

gcc: fatal error: no input files

compilation terminated.

configure:2861: $? = 1

configure:2884: checking for C compiler default output file name

configure:2911: gcc    conftest.c  >&5

gcc: error: spawn: No such file or directory

configure:2914: $? = 1

configure:2952: result:

configure: failed program was:

| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "SystemC"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "systemc"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.3.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "SystemC 2.3.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my issue. In my .cshrc file, I had modified the $path variable and actually removed gcc and g++. Thus, gcc and g++ both were not working and so the configure script was failing when it tried to run them.

I fixed up my cshrc and the $path variable now has /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/g++ and the configure script runs successfully.